# Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame but its the exact same domain?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, browser

So I am trying to get this link from an iFrame which is hosted on my own site. They both have the same domain but somehow it still gives me this error message:
Blocked a frame with origin ... from accessing a cross-origin frame.
How is this possible and how can I fix this.

Comment: Posting your code will help us help you debug.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a better question.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame) article that might solve your problem.